# Trying to zip a excel file with password protection but file corrupts Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to zip an excel file with password protection. I have checked the file without zipping and it's fine. In regards to the zip code I am generating a password protected zip file but for some reason, it is corrupting the excel file within. Any help is appreciated

```
    import pyzipper

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_multiple.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df2')
writer.save()



with pyzipper.AESZipFile('Extract.zip','w',
                         encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as zf:
    zf.setpassword(password)
    zf.write('pandas_multiple.xlsx')

with pyzipper.AESZipFile('Extract.zip') as zf:
    zf.pwd = password
    my_secrets = zf.read('pandas_multiple.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

`zf.writestr('pandas_multiple.xlsx')`  looks extremely suspicious, in fact I'm surprised the code runs at all: [writestr takes a filename *and contents*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) but you're only giving the filename. Indeed when I try to run the code I get the expected:

```
TypeError: writestr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

If you want to store a file in a zip archive, you're supposed to use [`ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write). If I do so:

```py
with pyzipper.AESZipFile('GoTo Extract.zip','w',
                       encryption=pyzipper.WZ_AES) as zf:
    zf.setpassword(password)
    zf.write(fname)

with pyzipper.AESZipFile('GoTo Extract.zip') as zf:
    zf.pwd = password
    contents = zf.read(fname)
```

I get exactly the contents I put in.

Comment: Updated the code above. I still get a corrupted Excel file. I have also added in the code I use to create the file

Comment: @DGDATA still works fine here. Added a random generation of two dataframes, and wrote `my_secrets` back to disk, I get the same file as originally generated and both open without issues in libreoffice calc.